# Copy to 14 / Copy to GAC functionality in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio, wspbuilder

Hey there, for those used to working with WSP Builder, does anyone know of a way to get the same "Copy to hive" and "Copy to GAC" functionality in SP 2010 and VS 2010 that was in WSP Builder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out Community Kit for SharePoint: Development Tools Edition. 
It has Quick deploy and loads of other nifty stuff for VS2010
[CKS:DEV](http://cksdev.codeplex.com/)

Answer (score 1):

By the way WSPBuilder has a beta for 2010. If Copy to 14/GAC is all you need, you can use it as well.

Comment: What I think is better in WSPBuilder is the availability of built in shortcuts that let you avoid too much mousing about.

Answer (score 0):

There is a DeploymentTarget attribute in the Package manifest which can be set to either GlobalAssemblyCache or WebApplication, which should replicate the WSPBuilder switch.